# c# DLL not visible

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, com

I have a C# DLL which I can successfully register on PC A and PC B (both run Visual Studio 2010.)
However, when I want to add a Reference to the DLL on PC B in VS, it is not listed under the COM library tab, whereas on PC A it is listed.

I registered the DLL on both systems with the command

```
regasm.exe MyDll.dll /codebase /tlb
```

Just to double check, I used an external Tool to view registered DLLs and my DLL was listed on both computers, as it should.

Does anybody have an Idea why that is?

Greetings and Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why not add a reference to the dll directly?

Comment: let's assume that we mustn't. We did manage to get it working that way, but we would like to solve it this way, too.

Comment: Using the wrong version of Regasm.exe is a common mistake.  VS is a 32-bit program so will only look at the 32-bit registry keys.  And thus requires the 32-bit version of Regasm.exe

Answer (score 0):

It should be visible under the "Assemblys"-tab since it is a managed DLL.

edit:

Try to register the DLL like this:

```
gacutil /i MyDll.dll
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it isn't listed under Assemblys either.

Comment: Did you restart your development environment?

Comment: We restarted both systems twice, just to be sure. Still nothing :(